# Animation with AngularJS directives

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple AngularJS app with a `<div>` and 3 buttons. When a button is clicked, the object that the `<div>` is bound to is changed to update the position of the `<div>`. What I would like to  do is have the `<div>` slide into its new position rather than just instantly appear there. I know how to create angularjs directives and how to use jQuery.animate, but in this case I want to click one type of element but manipulate another. I'm also working on the principle of only manipulating the DOM from within directives.

http://jsfiddle.net/s66Ha/4/

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div style="position: relative; height: 100px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: {{current.left}}px; top: {{current.top}}px;">X</div>
</div>

<button ng-repeat="coord in coords" ng-click="move(coord)">{{$index}}</button>
```

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.coords = {
        0: {left: "20", top: "10"},
        1: {left: "40", top: "20"},
        2: {left: "60", top: "30"}
    };

    $scope.current = $scope.coords[0];

    $scope.move = function(coord){
        $scope.current = coord;
    }
});
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can simply use transition property of CSS3.

Like this :

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: {{current.left}}px; top: {{current.top}}px;transition:all 500ms linear;">X</div>
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s66Ha/5/)</kbd>

Comment: This works but won't help with browsers that don't support CSS3.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery only then you need to use $watch and apply css using .animate inside $watch.

Comment: I don't specifically want to use jQuery but I do want to use best AngularJS practices. Your fiddle works. Why is it not recommended?

Comment: It is recommended but I've used it inside controller which is not right way. AngularJS best practices says that you should do DOM manipulation inside directives.